# lupdate doesn't create .ts translations file

Tags: file, qt, localization, translation, qt-creator

So, i've ran into a problem. When i use lupdate on Qt Creator (Tools -> External -> Linguist -> Update Translations (lupdate))  the translations files aren't created.

I've added the "TRANSLATIONS +=" on the .pro file

```
TRANSLATIONS    +=  localization/localization_es.ts
```

But still the translations files aren't created. localization/ path exist on the project folder, but still, no files are created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Project is 4.8.1, for some reason lupdate and lrelease don't work. So I've made the .ts using cmd using 4.7.4 binaries.

Answer (score -1):

To make it work in 4.8.1, just run lupdate and lrelease with absolute path.
I have run it from absolute path on my computer C:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\mingw\bin\lupdate myproject.pro
and C:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\mingw\bin\lrelease tranlate_js.ts.

It will ask for some dll files first time, just place required files at same path or in system folder.

Your lupdate and lrelease will start working from Qt creator.

---

Thanks

Comment: I have this problem with `lrelease` from qttools version 5.15.10 from GNU Guix, for example when attempting to build `x2goclient` it fails with: 
`/gnu/store/yx0absq38k1w4amz04fv3vvi01pfyz4q-qttools-5.15.10/bin/lrelease x2goclient.pro
WARNING: Could not find qmake spec 'default'.`
As you can see, using an absolute file name for lrelease didn't help.