# How to add translation file to Qt in Ubuntu

Tags: qt, ubuntu-22.04, qtranslator

I am not able to create a translation file in a Qt Creator Widgets project.

In `main.cpp`, `mainwindow.cpp` and `mainwindow.h`, I have:

```c++
#include <QTranslator>
```

In the pro file I have

```qmake
TRANSLATIONS = lang_en.ts
```

I should note that:

- I cannot start Qt Creator from the program search but only from the terminal.
- I have also tried new empty projects.
- I can add one translation file when creating a new project.

When I execute `lupdate` from the GUI it prints:

```bash
Starting external tool "/usr/lib/qt6/bin/lupdate /home/moritz/C++/Georechner.pro"
```

When I execute:

```bash
lupdate -verbose ~/C++/GeoRechner/Georechner_aktuell/Georechner.pro
```

in the terminal, it prints:

```
WARNING: Could not find qmake spec 'default'.
```

And no `.tr` file is to be found. I suppose I am missing some Qt language installation or update or something of the kind?

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.

Related:

- [How to add translation files to Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40864501/how-to-add-translation-files-to-qt)
- [Qt 5 Documentation: Hello tr() Example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtlinguist-hellotr-example.html)
- [How to add translation file to Qt in Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77599560/how-to-add-translation-file-to-qt-in-ubuntu)

Comment: I suspect you may have a conflict between Qt installed from Ubuntu, and Qt installed from qt.io. For non-Ubuntu-specific Qt development, I'd recommend removing all Ubuntu Qt dev packages, installing Qt with Qt Online Installer to default location under home directory, and for command line work adding that bin folder to your path. Use `which` command in terminal to make sure right program versions get run.

Comment: If you use Ubuntu Qt, then you may have missing packages, or indeed conflict with a different Qt version...

Comment: under options> Kits> Qt Versions   there is Qt 6.2.4 (System)  /usr/bin/qmake6  listed. At the bottom it says "no QML utility installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Janjua's answer from here did it:
[lupdate doesn't create .ts translations file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12079327/lupdate-doesnt-create-ts-translations-file?rq=2)

On my system the lupdate file to execute (because there are several),
is

`/home/moritz/Qt/6.6.0/gcc_64/bin/lupdate`
so in total :

```
/home/moritz/Qt/6.6.0/gcc_64/bin/lupdate ~/path/to/project/projectname.pro
```